# Why cant i see the string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I know this code is sloppy, but I'm wondering why when I'm using the ReadProcessMemory() function I can't see the string stored in the relevant address.

```
    //If the game window is open then this function grabs the process ID.
if(FinderCheck)
{
    DWORD procID;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);

    //All so access you can read and write to process memory.
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,procID);

    if(procID = NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: Failed to Obtain Process ID" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while(true)
        {


        //To read the process memory this line writes the memory data to buffer
        //Remember to change the address every time you boot the process or it will not work.
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (PBYTE*)0xDC8F1AA904,&Cursor,sizeof(Cursor),0);
        cout << Cursor << endl;
        cout << "Test" << endl;

        Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand this is probably really sloppy code. I'm open to suggestions for improvements.

Comment: first suggestion: your paragraph is a wall of text. It's really tiresome to read. You should improve on that first.

Comment: After you fix the typo pointed out below, add error checking to all of the Windows functions you call. Right now if it doesn't work you'll have no idea why. You may also have more success asking for the actual permissions you need rather than PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS.

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings.  It would have caught the mistake that arorias pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(procID = NULL)
```

Sadly, this if statement will always evaluate to false, you are missing the second "=". This also means that from this point `procID` is `NULL`.

What about the rest of the code? Can you show us how the definition of the `Cursor` looks like and how do you implemented `operator<<`?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. In the answer should really go just that: a answer. Requesting clarifications go in the comments. When you will have enough rep you will be able to post comments.